# Multiple TF issues while running SLAM

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, tf2, 3dslam, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ETH zurich's version of ORB SLAM on a bagfile of Kitti dataset of Stereo Images which I am playing at 0.1 r.
The SLAM publishes TF in the camera's frame,
`world->cam0`

1. I am trying to publish a static transform between cam0 and base-link the following code using in the launch file,

while I am able to see it when I echo /tf_static

```
sal@sal:~/helper_ws$ rostopic echo /tf_static 
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs:         0
      frame_id: "base_link"
    child_frame_id: "cam0"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 1.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.5
      rotation: 
        x: -0.499999841466
        y: 0.499601836645
        z: -0.499999841466
        w: 0.500398163355
---
```

but when I do rosrun tf view_frames this is what I get
[image: image description]

I am also unable to visualize it in Rviz which says no transform exists between cam0 and base_link

This same problem exists when I run S-PTAM slam ,I wrote a small code to subscribe to pose and republish a transform between a new frame odom to the cam_link and still face the same issue.
This issue only occurs  when I publish a static transform on moving frame  like cam0 if I instead publish on some other new random frame everything works perfectly.

Not sure what is wrong.

```
<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="camera_broadcaster" args="1 0 0.5 -1.57 0 -1.57 base_link camera_link" />
```

[image: image description]

here is sample tf data from orb_slam:

```
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1385798169
        nsecs:  22117622
      frame_id: "world"
    child_frame_id: "cam0"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 25.4732408315
        y: -1.2908452135
        z: 79.1472754724
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0172311913033
        y: 0.69976084093
        z: 0.00217123302013
        w: 0.714166043224
---
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1385798169
        nsecs:  22117622
      frame_id: "world"
    child_frame_id: "cam0"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 25.4732408315
        y: -1.2908452135
        z: 79.1472754724
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0172311913033
        y: 0.69976084093
        z: 0.00217123302013
        w: 0.714166043224
---
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1385798169
        nsecs:  23126248
      frame_id: "world"
    child_frame_id: "cam0"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 25.4732408315
        y: -1.2908452135
        z: 79.1472754724
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0172311913033
        y: 0.69976084093
        z: 0.00217123302013
        w: 0.714166043224
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293043/multiple-tf-issues-while-running-slam/) by [Salahuddin_Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32372/salahuddin_khan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2018-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
Did you solve the problem?
I think it is because that one child frame can not have more one parent.

---

Originally posted by [songyima](https://answers.ros.org/users/40666/songyima/) with karma: 26 on 2020-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Salahuddin_Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32372/salahuddin_khan/) on 2020-01-16**:
Yes, you're right, that was the problem.